# Wordpress menu class for li.current-menu-item not being applied

Tags: css, wordpress, menu

I am creating a Wordpress site for a client at http://digitaldemo.net/vintage/about/ and I am 
just about done. The only problem I am running into is that the li.current-menu-item class is not being applied when I am on a given page.

For example, on the above URL, the About menu item should have a darker gray background instead of 
the white "spotlight" behind the icon.

Here is the CSS for my navigation:

```
/* Navigation */

.topnav {
    width:960px ;
    position:absolute ;
    top:0 ;
    left:0 ;
    z-index:5000 ;
    text-align:center ;
}

ul.menu {
    margin-left:0 ;
    padding-left:0 ;
    list-style-type:none ;
}

.menu li {
    display:inline-block ;
}

.menu li {
    margin:0px 12px 12px 12px ;
    height:130px ;
    width:130px ;
}

.menu li a {
    font-family:ParkLaneNF ;
    color:#000000 ;
    font-size:20px ;
    font-weight:normal ;
    text-align:center ;
    text-decoration:none ;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 3px #333333 ;
    display:inline-block ;
    line-height:130px ;
    height:76px ;
    width:130px ;
    padding-top:54px ;
}

.menu li.home {
    background:url("images/homepage-icon.png") no-repeat center ;
}

.menu li.home:hover, .menu li.home .current_page_item {
    background:url("images/homepage-icon-over.png") no-repeat center ;
}


.menu li.blog {
    background:url("images/blog-icon.png") no-repeat center ;
}

.menu li.blog:hover, .menu li.blog .current-menu-item {
    background:url("images/blog-icon-over.png") no-repeat center ;
}


.menu li.store {
    background:url("images/store-icon.png") no-repeat center ;
}

.menu li.store:hover, .menu li.store .current_page_item {
    background:url("images/store-icon-over.png") no-repeat center ;
}

.menu li.about {
    background:url("images/about-icon.png") no-repeat center ;
}

.menu li.about:hover, .menu li.about .current-page-item {
    background:url("images/about-icon-over.png") no-repeat center ;
}


.menu li.contact {
    background:url("images/contact-icon.png") no-repeat center ;
}

.menu li.contact:hover, .menu li.contact current-menu-item {
    background:url("images/contact-icon-over.png") no-repeat center ;
}
```

Each li has a unique background image (e.g. li.blog has the blog icon and spotlight, li.about has
the  about icon and spotlight, etc...)

If anyone can help me sort out this issue, I'd really appreciate it.

Best,

Cynthia

Answer (score 0):

Your selectors are wrong.

To select your LI with class `current-menu-item` you need to have it without spaces:

```
li.about.current-menu-item { ... }
```

Also it is quite confusing with the names

```
current-page-item
```

and

```
current_page_item
```

Change these for your own good.